# Highcharts Caption when verticalAlign set to 'top' margin does not work

Tags: highcharts

Hi I a'm trying to position caption on 'top' and control margin between caption and plotArea using caption.margin property. Works perfectly for 'bottom' aligned caption, but not 'top'. Please advise. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/e7kdz32v/11/:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 4, 3, 5],
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Fruits'
    }],
    caption: {
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      margin: 100,
      text: '<b>The caption renders in the top, and is part of the exported chart.</b>'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That works in the opposite way as a margin for title: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4w3az2qd/. As a solution, instead of `caption` you can use `title`, `subtitle` or `caption` with `padding-bottom` style:

```
caption: {
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
        'padding-bottom': '100px'
    },
    text: '<b>The caption renders in the top, and is part of the exported chart.</b>'
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j8gv1k9L/

**API Refefence:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/caption.useHTML